# Cisco Yang Suite - NGINX HTTP Host Header Error

Tags: python, docker, http, nginx, yang

I installed Cisco Yang Suite using this [repo](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/yangsuite)

After running through the bash script and it comes up I get HTTP 400 Bad Request from a remote machine and in the debug, I get the bellow error.

```
docker-yangsuite-1  | [31/Jan/2023 10:27:50] ERROR [django.security.DisallowedHost:75] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'enauto.homelab.com:8443'. You may need to add 'enauto.homelab.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I navigate into production.py script and amend the allowed hosts to the below but still get the error even after removing the images and re-composing.

```
if 'DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS' in os.environ:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', 'localhost').split()
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = 'localhost','enauto.homelab.com','192.168.1.51'
```

I am expecting to navigate to the web front end of the application

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran the `start_yang_suite.sh` script from that repo, a file called `yangsuite/setup.env` is created ([see source](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/yangsuite/blob/5b17e37c6157a338885f3d70b314a4a8afacaf5a/docker/start_yang_suite.sh#L98)), that contains the `DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS` env var, so the `production.py` part will **not** run the `else`, but use the env-file's value.

So if you just add you domain to the env file, you should be fine. Default seperator for `split()` is a white space, so

```
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS="localhost enauto.homelab.com"
```

should be good to go.